# Torch, Where are .pth files saved

Tags: python, pytorch

This is a painful question to ask, but I can't figure it out. So I save my model weights to FILE and obviously they're saved on my computer somewhere, I can load them up again and switch between .pth files. But I have absolutely no idea where they're being saved to.

```
FILE ="test.pth"
torch.save(policy.state_dict(), FILE)

policy.load_state_dict(torch.load("test.pth"))
policy.eval()
```

Any help very much appreciated, really.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The files are saved in the directory you execute your code from. You can find this directory as follows:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()) # get current working directory
```

Comment: Directory is just desktop, python file on desktop. The .pth file doesn't appear anywhere. Thanks for the answer, man.